# C# Receive over UDP

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am writing a program that has to send data over UDP to a specific server (which works) and also receive data from that server (which doesn't work).
The problem is, that the port i am sending data to is not the same that dat from the server come from.

Server: Listens on one port, creates new sockets (on different ports) for each client to send data.

I have the following code (client side):

```
socker = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint epLocal = new IPEndPoint(myIp, localPort);
socket.Bind(epLocal);
IPAddress ipAddressremote = IPAddress.Parse(remoteIp);
remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddressremote, port);
socket.Connect(remoteEP);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
socket.Send(someByteArray);
```

This successfully connects to my server application and sends the data it's supposed to. However, MessageCallBack never gets called:

```
private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult iAsyncResult)
{
byte[] receivedData = (byte[])iAsyncResult.AsyncState;
ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
string receievedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(receivedData);
handleMessage(receievedMessage);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);
}
```

I think the problem is that the client socket is still connected to the port on the server, and only accepts data from that port, but to my knowledge this isn't a problem when using BeginReceive instead of BeginReceiveFrom.

Comment: Why does UDP server need to create a new socket for every client?

Comment: i figured thats the way to go if the server needs to send data to multiple clients... am i wrong there?

Comment: There is really no reason for this. Single socket will serve just fine.

Comment: got it to work with just a single socket, thank you! don't even know why i did this some other way in the first place :D

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at [UdpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) though, it might make your life much easier.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i will take a look at it! I am new to all this socket-stuff so i want to complete this project just using sockets :D but my program works fine now

Answer (score 0):

When using UDP you can't use the Send and BeginReceive methods, because those are connection-oriented (TCP). Instead use the [Socket.SendTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eae4f5y0(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Socket.BeginReceiveFrom.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceivefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) It should work using those methods.

Comment: You *can* use `Send()` and `BeginReceive()` with UDP, but they require the socket to be bound to specific IP/port pairs, whether TCP or UDP, which is why data cannot be received from a different port.  `SendTo()` and `BeginReceiveFrom()` do not have that binding requirement.

Comment: True, but I generally use sendto and begin to avoid confusion

Comment: Sending UDP packets without a binding is the *typical* usage, but sending packets with a binding has uses, too. To establish a session between two specific peers and let the OS ignore packets from unwanted peers outside the session.